# Disable PSPDFKit thumbnail

Tags: ios, objective-c, thumbnails, pspdfkit

I'm trying to disable the thumbnail [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TvVC.png) that comes with PSPDFKit, I'm not sure exactly what its called so I'm having a really hardtime finding it in the code. Anyone that has used this library before have any idea where this thumbnail is coming from, what its called, or has anything that might help! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a modifiable source-level license to PSPDFKit?  If not, then your life is going to get very hard.

Comment: i think we do, it only shows once as soon as i flip a page its gone.

Comment: set scrobbleBarEnabled = NO; like   
    yourPSPDFViewController.scrobbleBarEnabled = NO;
this will hide the ThumbnailPreView of the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Disable the ScrobbleBar(Thumbnail Preview) and Position Overlay(Page no:) of the PDF in PSPDFKit**
you have to do the following

```
PSPDFViewController *pdfController = [[PSPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:yourMagazine];

pdfController.scrobbleBarEnabled = NO; // Disable the Bottom Scrobble Bar
pdfController.pageLabelEnabled = NO; // Disables the bottom document site position overlay.
```

Comment: I actually set both scrobbleBarEnabled and pageLabelEnabled to NO but some how its is still appearing. No where else in the code I see them set to YES. Any other thing that might be causing them to appear? @steipete Thanks for answering!